# Spark: "SparkException: Task not serializable" when joining a to-be transformed Dataset

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following codes. It performs a join operation on two `Dataset`s, one of which is being filtered inside the `join` transformation.

```
activeUserProfileDataset.join(
      allJobModelsDataset.filter(jobModel => jobIdRecCandidatesBroadcasted.value.contains(jobModel.JobId)),
      $"notVisitedJobId" === col(JobModelFieldNames.jobId),
      "left_outer")
```

This caused problem:

> SparkException: Task not serializable

However, when I take out the `filter` transformation and create the second `Dataset` outside of `join`, this time works:

```
val jobIdRecCandidatesJobModels = allJobModelDataset.filter(jobModel => jobIdRecCandidatesBroadcasted.value.contains(jobModel.JobId))

val userJobPredictionsDataset3 = userJobPredictionsDataset2.join(
      jobIdRecCandidatesJobModels,
      $"notVisitedJobId" === col(JobModelFieldNames.jobId),
      "left_outer")
```

Could you explain to me why is this? Could you tell me how these transformation operations (like join, filter) works internally?
Thanks!

Comment: That's weird. Can you add output of `explain(true)` method in two cases ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because in Spark you can't specify transformations inside another transformations.
The main idea:

- Driver node processes DAGs and creates tasks
- Workers execute transformations (in form of tasks)

In first example you try to process DAGs and create tasks INSIDE a transformation (on a worker node). Generally you crate a task that need to create tasks on another DF). But remember -  workers can't create new tasks. They only execute them.

In second example - you do everything correctly on driver node. E.g. you first create transformations on DF and then you just use resulting DF in new task.

Hope that helps :)